# Compare multiple column with single value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is my table structure

```
ID    DATE1           DATE2         DATE3
1     2018-05-01      2018-05-01    2018-11-11
2     2018-05-01      2018-10-01    2018-05-01
3     2018-05-01      2018-05-01    2018-05-01
```

Here actually I wanted to select record where any one of the three dates is greater than now()

like - `(DATE1, DATE2, DATE3) > NOW()::DATE`

Can anyone let me know that how can I achieve this in where clause 
instead of writing like

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
where DATE1 > NOW()::DATE
  AND DATE2 > NOW()::DATE
  AND DATE3 > NOW::DATE
```

Actually, I am going to compare all dates column with the single value, so just wanted to know is there any other efficient way that I can use instead of adding the condition for each column.

Comment: I assume the NOW value will only be evaluated once for each query anyway.

Comment: `NOW()::DATE` can be simplified to `current_date`

Comment: You say "where any one of the three dates is greater than now()", but then you test all dates > now(). Do you mean any or all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `GREATEST()`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE GREATEST(date1, date2, date) > CURRENT_DATE;
```

I think `CURRENT_DATE` makes more sense than converting `NOW()`.

Comment: @Gordan,
Thanks for the answer.
Just let me know one more thing, that how we can compare it with NULL.

Comment: @TusharKulkarni, Start with adding a few null values to the sample table data, and adjust the expected result accordningly.